# React-native with different behaviors in production and developed mode

Tags: android, react-native, axios

I am developed my first app and when I run it in production mode (after downloaded by google play) the behavior of the app in physic device was different than deve mode.
I am just make a internal testing. In the physic device not show errors.

When I use the emulator device it's run perfect in production mode (without uses Google Play download).
When I installed the app in production mode at my physic device through the .apk generated by react-native, everything run fine (I make a transfer by USB port to install).
The file send to Google Play is .aab extension.

I don't now how to check this problem.

**Strange Behavior:**

In the physic device I can't make a request by Axios (Login in the server). More than one request not work fine.

**Try:**

I did try uses fetch function, but not run too.

The basic not run, so , I can't check if there are others errors.

Tips to check?